# Emulate yield return for IObservable

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

When I don't know how to do generate some enumerable using LINQ, I just create my own extension method and use the `yield` keyword. This gives me a closure where I can store things such as a counter or some other aggregate values.

In an `IObservable` I don't know if there is a built-in way to do this. I recently wanted to generate an observable which, given another `IObservable<string>`, ignores everything until a starting value (say "start") appears in the source, and then starts ignoring everything until the source yields an ending value (say "end").

So if, for instance my source was `{"1", "start", "2", "3", "end", "4", "start", "5", "end}`, the new observable should be `{"2", "3" "5"}`.

There may be a way to do this using IObservable's built-int methods, but it'd be straightforward to do using the yield keyword if it were an `IEnumerable`. So I wonder if there is a similar straightforward way to do it for an IObservable.

I came up with this small class that basically does the job:

```
public class ClosureSelectMany<TSource, TResult> : IObservable<TResult>
{
    private readonly IObservable<TSource> _Source;
    private readonly Func<Func<TSource, IObservable<TResult>>> _Selector;

    public ClosureSelectMany(IObservable<TSource> source, Func<Func<TSource, IObservable<TResult>>> selector)
    {
        _Source = source;
        _Selector = selector;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TResult> observer)
    {
        var selector = _Selector();
        return _Source.SelectMany(selector).Subscribe(observer);
    }
}

public static class ObservableHelpers
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> ClosureSelectMany<TSource, TResult>(this IObservable<TSource> source, Func<Func<TSource, IObservable<TResult>>> selector)
    {
        return new ClosureSelectMany<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
    }
}
```

I can then use it like:

```
test = input.ClosureSelectMany<string, string>(() =>
{
    bool running = false;

    return val =>
    {
        if (val == "end")
            running = false;

        var result = running ? Observable.Return(val) : Observable.Empty<string>();

        if (val == "start")
            running = true;

        return result;
    };
});
```

Which looks like what I'd do if I'd use yield keyword in an IEnumerable.

So I wonder if I'm reinventing the wheel and there's already some built-in function that does this, and if not why. Perhaps this method could can cause any other problem I'm not seeing right now.

Comment: I don't think you're reinventing the wheel, but another question - do you want to return empty or do you want to skip to the next "visible" value?

Comment: Returning empty from inside a SelectMany selector causes the resulting observable to skip it, so I think they're the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Observable.Create` instead of composing existing operators together, though composition is generally a much better idea whenever possible.

Note that `Create` also has overloads that accept `Task`-returning functions, allowing you to define an [async iterator](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/async-iterators.aspx) -- a coroutine that uses *await* instead of *yield*, although that's not what you need here in particular.

However, your problem can be solved by composing `Scan`, `Where` and `Select`:

```
xs.Scan(
  new { Running = false, Value = default(string) }, 
  (previous, current) => new
  {
    Running = current == "start" || (previous.Running && current != "end"), 
    Value = current
  })
  .Where(state => state.Running && state.Value != "start")
  .Select(state => state.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `yield return` equivalent for observables. It would certainly be something that could be baked in to the compiler, but it's just not available at this point in time.

However, with the available operators it is quite easy to do what you want.

This worked for me:

```
var results =
    source
        .Publish(ss =>
            ss
                .Window(
                    ss.Where(s0 => s0 == "start"),
                    s => ss.Where(s1 => s1 == "end"))
                .Select(xs => xs.Skip(1).SkipLast(1))
                .Merge());
```

Given this source:

```
var source = new []
{
    "1", "start", "2", "3", "end", "4", "start", "5", "end"
}.ToObservable();
```

I get this output:

```
2 
3 
5
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to clarify that the focus here is in the alternative to **yield return**.

Second, this particular example problem could be resolved as this:

```
bool running = false;
Observable.ToObservable(new [] {"1", "start", "2", "3", "end", "4", "start", "5", "end"})
    .Where(s => {
        if (s == "start") running = true;            
        if (s == "end") running = false;                                    
        return (running && s != "start");
    })
    .Dump();
```

Now, to the answer:

You would need to remember that **yield return** is just syntax sugar that saves you from having to implement IEnumerable and IEnumerator yourself.

You could think of it as a combination of IEnumerator.MoveNext() and IEnumerator.Current, without the need of an extra class to save the state of the enumerator, as explained in MSDN docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).

You may also have read that the IObservable is the asynchronous/push "**dual**" to the synchronous/pull IEnumerable (http://reactivex.io/intro.html).

With all that in mind, you could think that the  IObservable equivalent to yield return (IEnumerator.MoveNext() + IEnumerator.Current) is the **IObserver.OnNext(T value)** method.

Thinking that way, you could easily implement what you need as in this sample (tested in LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    var q = FilteredSource.Generate();
    q.Dump();
}

public class FilteredSource
{
    public static IObservable<string> Generate()
    {           
        var q = from s in OriginalSource.Generate()
                select s;

        return Observable.Create<string>(
            async observer =>
            {           
                bool produce = false;                
                try
                {
                    await q.ForEachAsync(s => {

                        if (s == "start")
                            produce = true;

                        if (s == "end")
                            produce = false;                        

                        if (produce && s != "start")
                            observer.OnNext(s);                        
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    observer.OnError(ex);
                }

                observer.OnCompleted();

                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
    }
}

public class OriginalSource
{
    public static IObservable<string> Generate()
    {
        return Observable.Create<string>(
            observer =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] list = {"1", "start", "2", "3", "end", "4", "start", "5", "end"};
                    foreach (string s in list)
                        observer.OnNext(s);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    observer.OnError(ex);
                }

                observer.OnCompleted();

                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
    }            
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Why not use `new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToObservable()` instead of your `OriginalSource.Method`? But also when you use `Observable.Create` with `return Disposable.Empty;` you are creating an observable that cannot be stopped. Try adding `OriginalSource.Generate().Do(x => x.Dump())` and doing `var q = FilteredSource.Generate().Take(2);` - you'll see that the original observable runs to completion even though the query completed. If the original observable was infinite then this is a memory leak.

Comment: I would suggest that you test what you say before post it.in LINQPad.: "OriginalSource.Generate().Take(2).Dump();". The output is "1", "start". Besides, I was just focusing in answering the question.

Comment: @Enimagtivity, in a more polite way, please let me ask: did you test your suggestions? Try it in LINQPad. For example,for "OriginalSource.Generate().Take(2).Dump();", the output is "1", "start", as expected. Regarding the argument that OriginalSource runs to completion: that is the intended outcome, as it runs to completion while the Filtered one looks for instances of start and end, to determine what to pass to its observer. Also please consider that I was just focusing in answering the question about the **yield return** alternative for IObservable.

Comment: Please retry my suggestion - you coded it wrongly. The `.Take(2)` is on the filtered observable, not the original source. I test everything before I post.

Comment: @Enigmativity: That effect is not because Disposable.Empty but instead because the foreach in the original source. In this context, IDisposable is not used to manage resources, but to manage subscription lifetime. The subscriber does not control the Enumerable  lifetime this way (you would use a CancellationToken instead). For example, when you unsubscribe to mouse events, the events continue being generated, you just don't consume them anymore.

Comment: That's not true. If you change my code with the `.Take(2)` as above the source terminates early - I tested that before I posted. And `Disposable.Empty` does not "manage subscription lifetime" - it does nothing other than provide a dummy object to return. The subscriber **does** control the enumerable lifetime. As for your mouse events example, that's not true either - events are only when where there are handlers - no handlers no events.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html